# javascript value is always undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined

In javascript the value of a variable is always undefined, even if i assign a value to it.

```
var test = 0;
voti = new Array({
  0: [0, 1]
});  

$('body').on('click', '.handle-add-translation', function(e, obj) {
  if (voti[test] > 0) {
    var startCounterAnswerMultiplChoiceTranslation = voti[voti.length - 1];

  }
});
```

the variable test is always undefined , can anybody explain this to me ?

Comment: I would delete this question before you get downvotted into oblivion.

Comment: `new Array({0:[0,1]})` is an array with one object in it. `voti[0]` is that object, and an object it can't sensibly compared to the number `0` in a greater-than comparison. What did you expect to happen? (I'm not asking that sarcastically, by the way -- I'm asking you to clarify your question by being explicit about how you expected your code to work.)

Comment: in new array, you need to pass elements of array as params like this 
voti = new Array(0,1);

Comment: where are you checking the value of test , it obviously can't be undefined !!

Comment: @Pytth Just like how you got downvoted? :)

Comment: *"the variable test is always undefined"* Not sure how test would be undefined when you set it to zero.

Comment: `if (voti[test] > 0)` makes no sense since you are comparing an object to a number. So is something else overriding the variable?

Comment: @epascarello I still don't get why my answer was downvoted.

Comment: @Pytth So Length of an Array is one. Subtract one and it is zero. Which is the last index.... AKA The last beer is beer ZERO, not beer one.

Comment: @apsillers the problem is that when i check if (voti[test] >0) this comparation never works because test is always undefined